# Trying to set the caret at the end of a contenteditable div on focus and then press enter for new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm running this code to set the caret at the end of a contenteditable when the div is focused. I'm also running a script on enter key to fix linebreak weirdness in firefox. For some reason the two functions don't work together and I get this message on enter:

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed
>   amount

Try to click on the div and press enter in Firefox and you'll see what I mean. It works in Safari and Chrome.

I can't use a textarea, but is there a cleaner way to solve this? I also added a `setTimeout` on the `placeCaretAtEnd` function because it sometimes placed the caret where I pressed anyway, and sometimes it selects a portion of the text instead of placing it at the end. It still acts odd every now and then so suggestions of a more bulletproof way to make it always appear at the end is welcome!

```js
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

$(document).on('keydown', 'div', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  var $self = $(this);
  var esc = keyCode == 27;
  var nl = keyCode == 13;
  var tab = keyCode == 9;
  var shift = e.shiftKey;
  var sel, node, offset, text, textBefore, textAfter, range;

  if(nl)
  {
    sel = window.getSelection();

    // the node that contains the caret
    node = sel.anchorNode;

    // if ENTER was pressed while the caret was inside the input field

    // prevent the browsers from inserting <div>, <p>, or <br> on their own
    e.preventDefault();

    // the caret position inside the node
    offset = sel.anchorOffset;        

    // insert a '\n' character at that position
    text = node.textContent;
    textBefore = text.slice( 0, offset );
    textAfter = text.slice( offset ) || ' ';
    node.textContent = textBefore + '\n' + textAfter;

    // position the caret after that new-line character
    range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart( node, offset + 1 );
    range.setEnd( node, offset + 1 );

    // update the selection
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange( range );
  }
 });
 
$(document).on('focus', 'div', function(e) {
  var $self = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    placeCaretAtEnd($self[0]);
  },0);
});
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable>Lots of text
Lots of text
Lots of text</div>
```